# Why cookie is not set?

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, cross-domain, vapor

Do you have any idea why cookie is not set in client? It is sent from backend:

```swift
func loginEmail(_ req: Request) throws -> Response
{
    let response = Response(status: .ok)
    let cookie = HTTPCookies.Value(string: "abcdef")
    response.cookies["userId2"] = cookie
    return response
}
```

it is visible in browser in `Network` tab

```
set-cookie: userId2=abcdef; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

but not on `Application`
[image]

GET is sent to backend. Backend runs on 8080 port, frontend on 3000.

I use `axios` in a React / Next.js app for calling endpoint:

```js
const login = () => {
  axios
    .get(`http://localhost:8080/loginEmail`)
    .then((res) => {})
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};
```

I am using Vapor as backend, and has the following configurations, maybe they matter:

```swift
app.middleware.use(CORSMiddleware(configuration: .init(
    allowedOrigin: .originBased,
    allowedMethods: [.GET, .POST, .PUT, .OPTIONS, .DELETE, .PATCH],
    allowedHeaders: [.accept, .authorization, .contentType, .origin, .xRequestedWith, .userAgent, .accessControlAllowOrigin, .init("crossDomain"), .accessControlAllowCredentials, .xRequestedWith]
)))

app.sessions.configuration.cookieName = "userId2"

// Configures cookie value creation.
app.sessions.configuration.cookieFactory = { sessionID in
    print("sessionID.string: \(sessionID.string)")
    return .init(string: sessionID.string, isSecure: false)
}

app.middleware.use(app.sessions.middleware)
```

Comment: I removed React and Next.js tags as they're irrelevant, though you should probably provide more info on the backend.

Comment: I am using Vapor, I filled some configuration for CORS, maybe they matter

Comment: ok, I have made a bit of a progress, but still face other challanges: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922485/strange-behavior-when-set-session-with-axios-from-backend

Comment: If there's a Set Cookie header being sent then it's not a Vapor issue. Likely the JS front end isn't parsing the set cookie header in the response and saving the cookie. I still don't understand why you're trying to use cookies for a JS app, they're not designed to play nice together